# Express TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a undefined

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

so I've seen plenty of issues like the one I got, but I'm not understanding why this happens so please help a brother out.

I have a simple API with Express + Typescript, with two simple controllers.
Home controller, for the "default" landing route "localhost:port".
Pokemon controller, for getting pokemons, under the /pokemon route.

All routers are exported in an index.ts file and are imported in server.ts

**home.controller.ts**

```
import { Router, Request, Response } from "express";
const router: Router = Router();
router.get("/", (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    res.send("Hi, welcome to my Pokemon Api");
});
export const HomeController: Router = router;
```

**pokemon.controller.ts**

```
import { Router, Request, Response } from "express";
import Pokemon from "../entities/pokemon";
const router: Router = Router();
const pokemons: Pokemon[] = getPokemons(); // Get pokemons from a file/DB, irrelevant 

router.get("/", (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    if (pokemons !== undefined) {
        res.status(200).json(pokemons);
    } else {
        res.status(500).send("Error retrieving the list of Pokemons");
    }
});
export const PokemonController: Router = router;
```

**index.ts**

```
// note the order of these two controllers
export * from "./pokemon.controller";
export * from "./home.controller";
```

**server.ts**

```
import express from "express";
import { HomeController, PokemonController } from "./controllers";

const app: express.Application = express();
const port: number = 3000;

app.use("", HomeController);
app.use("/pokemon", PokemonController);

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Listening at port ${port}`);
});
```

Okay so exactly this code works 100% as expected.
However, if I switch the order of how I export the controllers in index.ts, it crashes.
So if instead of the above, I use
**index.ts**

```
export * from "./home.controller";
export * from "./pokemon.controller";
```

I get this error: TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a undefined.

Any idea of 1. why is the issue ocurring depending on the order (there must be something at the HomeController that I'm not getting and 2.how to fix it without just switching the order of export at index.ts?

**StackTrace:**

```
MYFOLDER\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:458
      throw new TypeError('Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a ' + gettype(fn))
            ^
TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a undefined
    at Function.use (D:\Mese\Documentos\Proyectos\Pokeapp\PokeApp.api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:458:13)
    at Function.<anonymous> (D:\Mese\Documentos\Proyectos\Pokeapp\PokeApp.api\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:220:21)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Function.use (D:\Mese\Documentos\Proyectos\Pokeapp\PokeApp.api\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:217:7)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Mese\Documentos\Proyectos\Pokeapp\PokeApp.api\app\server.ts:8:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Module.m._compile (D:\Mese\Documentos\Proyectos\Pokeapp\PokeApp.api\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:439:23)
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .ts] (D:\Mese\Documentos\Proyectos\Pokeapp\PokeApp.api\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:442:12)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
```

Comment: Which line is throwing the runtime error?  If you add `console.log(HomeController, PokemonController);` to `server.ts` after the imports, what do you see?  Where is `router` defined in `pokemon.controller.ts`?

Comment: I wasn't able to replicate in another PC, I'll try at home, looks very strange that I'm not able to replicate it, as it always appeared and the code is the same. I'll update this night. You can check the full thing in https://github.com/themese/Pokeapp.api in case you want to try and replicate yourself

Comment: Please, see the stacktrace, I just editted it. Thanks!

Comment: So now we're down to investigating why the problem occurs on one computer.  Does the problem still occur if you compile with `tsc` and run with `node build/server.js` instead of using `ts-node`?  What about if you add the `--no-cache` flag to your `ts-node` command?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I've been trying to replicate once again without success. I advanced the code a bit, so it could well be that I had some internal issues, can't really tell you what fixed it but no matter what I do, I can't replicate. Sorry for wasting your time, but really glad you took the time :)